# How to adjust y axis text and position according to the fill value in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple bar chart, and I want to set the Y axis labels in the middle position according to the correspondence fill value. I use `scale_y_discrete` to set the breaks and labels. However, only one label is shown. Can someone tell me what went wrong?

```
g = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(1), fill = factor(cyl))) + geom_bar(width = 1) 
tmp = table(mtcars$cyl)
tmp = cumsum(tmp) - (tmp /2)

g + scale_y_discrete(breaks = tmp, labels = tmp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this plot, the scale of the y-axis is not discrete. Therefore, you have to use `scale_y_continuous`.

```
g + scale_y_continuous(breaks = tmp, labels = tmp)
```

[image]